# Switch From Activity to Navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use Activity in my main Activity. and I would like to go **from my main Activity** to **navigation drawer activity** by clicking button on my main intent.

I created navigation drawer from navdrawer-wizard in android studio.

But i got an error when i click the button.

I use Api level 10. Android support Library v7,v4 is also inside my project.

I use Android studio.

i've debugged that issue it tigger the start activity But it gots and error in logcat like this.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{www.epicmyanmar.com.andropos/www.epicmyanmar.com.andropos.MyActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
```

Any help or any suggestion would be appricieate

`

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
`    `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="www.epicmyanmar.com.andropos.MyActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    `enter code here`<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        class="www.epicmyanmar.com.andropos.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

Comment: your error is within the navigation drawer xml file

Comment: did you declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes I've already declared

Comment: is there any possibility ?

Answer (score 0):

I got solutions By my self

Ker p peg is right.I found error in styles.xml .

Now i modified the style. normal Style for normal Activity.

and Nav-drawer style for Navdrawer activity.

Thanks every one